# How to access new YouTube Analytics Metrics (Impressions, Impressions CTR) from the API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

Can I already access Impressions and Impressions click-through rate from YouTube Analytics API?
These metrics are new. I saw the following document:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/huFTZ7HzePE.

But I could not find these metrics in [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics).

Please teach me about how to access Impressions and Impressions CTR from API.

Comment: I think it is not yet supported since it's new and can't be found in the documentation. We'll see in the upcoming days if this will be posted in the docs. Also, you can try asking in the help forum if it's rolled out in the YouTube API.

Comment: Hi MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0

Thank you for your reply. I see. I posted folowing help fofum. Please let me know, if you know how to direct contact rolled out about Youtube API.
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/fGCmqKHHSBc;context-place=topicsearchin/youtube/category$3Aother-topic$20kuwajima

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490683) on another identical StackOverflow question solves this problem.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148350289) in Google's issue-tracker that clearly states that (for now) it is NOT possible and in fact it is intended behavior (won't fix)!

I'll keep checking the [API's revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/revision_history) and try to keep this answer up to date.

Comment: Update to this: I filed a report for the same metrics, and was told that they were filing a feature request for this, but no promise that it would actually be implemented.