# Youtube Analytics API - Get Thumbnail-Impression Click-Through-Rate

Tags: google-api, youtube-analytics-api, impressions

One of the most important KPIs doesn't seem to be available via Youtube-Analytics-API. I can't get the total of thumbnail-impressions that have been shown to users. With that I could aggregate the impression-CTR using the views from certain traffic-sources (YT_SEARCH etc.). The [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics) don't seem to offer anything that would help me though.

Youtube-Reporting-API seems to have the same metrics as Youtube-Analytics-API. So I guess trying to use the Reporting-API would not help me either.

Is there any way to retrieve the number of thumbnail-impressions or the Impression-CTR programmatically? Any workaround? Am I missing something obvious? Or is there any intention of making that metric available via Analytics-API soon?

There is some very old, unanswered posts that may relate to my problem:

[How to access new YouTube Analytics Metrics (Impressions, Impressions CTR) from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50446222/how-to-access-new-youtube-analytics-metricsimpressions-impressions-ctr-from-a)

[Are Thumbnail Impressions/Views available through YouTube Analytics API?](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/43877763?hl=en)

Comment: How doesn't the second link answered your question? -  also, if via YouTube Studio you got those results, check the requests made in the website - so you might try web-scrapping such data (*or emulate the request(s)*). If you can provide more details, search on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) if someone else has posted the same problem you faced - or post a ticket there.

Comment: YouTube analytics is very limited, it also only stores data for 90 days last i remember. Have you checked the documentation and verified that what you are looking for is possible?  What have you tried please include your code and describe any issues you are having.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes the second link didn't answer my question because the only answer guides you to retrieving that number using Youtube Studio. Thanks for your tips though. I will read more about these ideas

Comment: @DaImTo My code works fine. There is no issue with it. Im retrieving many numbers already using the metrics available in the docs of Youtube Analytics API. But there is no metric for thumbnail-impressions. So I am asking if somebody knows a different way of retrieving that number. Thanks though

Comment: Have you finished your website? I recently come across the same issue, trying to get the thumbnail impression and CTR by official api, seems not possible.

Comment: I mean basically it's finished yes. But without impressions it's not moving towards production (yet), which of course is sad

Comment: I am unsure of what you mean by thumbnail impressions, but if I am right [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490683) on a very similar StackOverflow question solves this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148350289) in google's issue-tracker that clearly states that (for now) it is NOT possible and in fact it is intended behavior (won't fix)!

I'll keep checking the [API's Revision-History](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/revision_history) and try to keep this answer up to date.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28291040)

Comment: @AmitVerma This is an answer. Telling someone something is not possible (and in this case, backed up by a source), is an answer to the question.